# Manipulate date format

Tags: r, date, join, date-format, lubridate

While merging datasets, there are different kinds of date format that disable to join these datasets.

the values of date as a year unit is what I needed, like 2004, 2005, 1996, 1987.

but they have different format int, I_chr,  dbl.

I used various methods to manipulate but failed. Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

**the data sample 1 is**

```
glimpse(ARTD_data_reshaped)
Rows: 9,606
Columns: 12

$ country         chr "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afg~
$ year            I chr 1946, 1947, 1948, 1949, 1950, 1951, 1952, 1953, 1954, 1955, 1~
$ combined_regime chr "Monarchy", "Monarchy", "Monarchy", "Monarchy", "Monarchy", "Mon~
$ kailitz_tri     int 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0~
```

**the data sample 2 is**

```
glimpse(FH_data_2_reshaped_new)
Rows: 621
Columns: 3

$ country   chr "Abkhazia", "Abkhazia", "Abkhazia", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afg~
$ year      int 2003, 2004, 2005, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2003, 2004, 2005~
$ pr_rating chr "9", "9", "9", "8", "9", "13", "26", "26", "26", "11", "11", "10", "39~
```

**1. method 1**

```
FH_data_2_reshaped_new <- read.csv(file = "FH_data_2_reshaped.csv") %>% 
select(country, year, pr_rating) %>%
as.POSIXct(year)
```

> Error in as.POSIXct.default(., year) : 不知如何將 '.' 轉換成 “POSIXct” 類別

**2.  method 2**

```
FH_data_2_reshaped_new <- read.csv(file = "FH_data_2_reshaped.csv") %>% 
select(country, year, pr_rating) %>%
mutate(year = lubridate::year(year))
```

> Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `year`.
> i `year = lubridate::year(year)`.
> x 'origin' 一定得給值

Comment: Please consider adding the sample data using `dput(df)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways of doing this. One of the best ways to do it is using `as.Date` from base R.

**Note:** Assuming the name of the data frame is `df`.

The code will look like this:

```
df$year <- as.Date(df$year, format = "%Y")
```

This will convert the year column from the data frame to class `date`. Although it will append the current date and month to the year. i.e the year value will look be converted to a format `yyyy-mm-dd` where `mm` and `dd` are current month and date.

If you do not want the month and date part you can do it using `lubridate` library.

```
library(lubridate)
df$year <- as.Date(as.character(df$year), format = "%Y")
df$year <- year(df$year)
```

It will give you the only year part. But, remember that it will be of class `numeric` and not `Date`.